# Encoding and Select Case

Tags: vb.net

When i click on a button, my server sends a request to the client and then, the client is supposed to pass the request into a select case to figure out what to do.

But, it doesn't work. Let's say the server were to request "i", the client would receive "i" but would completely avoid my select case.

How can i fix this?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  If _TCPStream.DataAvailable Then
    Dim rcvdbytes(_TCPClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    _TCPStream.Read(rcvdbytes, 0, CInt(_TCPClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
    Dim request As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvdbytes)
    Execute_Action(request)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Execute_Action(ByVal request As String)
  msgbox(request) 'Says the request is "i" but do nothing
  Select Case request
    Case "i"
      messagebox.show("Hello")
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do this msgbox("[" & request & "]") or check the length of the string. Maybe there are space or hidden characters.

Comment: Apparently, my "i" has 8193 space characters.

This is bad, i guess i'm gonna have to learn RegEx

Comment: If it's a matter of whitespace, can you not call `.Trim()` instead of RegEx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have a hidden characters in this string. You should use Mid() function to select the proper substring.